# How to give path of service based database in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have added a **service based database(.mdf)**,to my Window form application project.But I

am not able to give the right path of the database. I am giving the path as follows but it

gives an exception that unable to open the connection

```
connection = new SqlConnection("user id=Sarao-PC\\Sarao;" +
                                      "password=sarao;server=SARAO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS" +
                                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                      "database=Database11 " +
                                      "connection timeout=30");
```

**Database11 is a service based database** .

What is the right way to give path of a **.mdf** file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you copy it from properties of your database? 
goto view tab, select server explorer. it opens up on your left, and you should see your database there, then just right click>properties. and there copy the text from the field 'Connection String'.

Answer (score 0):

You should write like below:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Security Connection strings

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to build the path to the file.

So how do you package the mdf file ? If you put it in your VS project, then you set Build action to "Content" you'll have the file in the same directory than you exe.
So to build the path it'll be easy:

```
string mdfPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyDb.mdf");
```

Then just create the connection string using this path:

```
connection = new SqlConnection("user id=Sarao-PC\\Sarao;" +
                                      "password=sarao;" +
                                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                      "database=Database11;" +
                                      "AttachDbFilename=" + mdfPath + ";");
```

Comment: What is the use of application configuration File. Is it also  have something related to connection string

Comment: it is giving an error path does not exist in current context.Is some file required to be added.

Comment: Yes, your mdf file is required ... of course you need to change the filename in my sample above ... it's not complicated, you just need to give the full path to the mdf. And you can read this path from config file if you want. My sample above just assume  the mdf if in the same directory than your exe file.